# Replace hyperlinks on shapes automatically

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint with a lot of textboxes that have a hyperlink to a specific cell in an Excel workbook. The location of the workbook has changed and now all "buttons" need to be redone for the hyperlinks. I don't want to do this by hand, so I thought I'd write a macro that cycles through the slides and checks all shapes in the presentation and replaces the hyperlinks.
What I need to do:

- Cycle through slides
- Cycle through each shape on those slides
- Check for hyperlinks
- If it has a hyperlink, replace it with the new location

So far, I can loop through the slides and shapes, but when I try to check for a hyperlink it can't find any. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()

    Dim sl As Object
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim hy As Hyperlink
    
    For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        sl.Select
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
        
            Set hy = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hy = sh.Hyperlinks.Address
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If Not hy Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox hy
            End If
            
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```

I added the `On Error Resume Next` to skip over the shapes without hyperlinks, but it never detects a hyperlink. I've been looking at this all day and I just can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `sh.Hyperlinks(1)`? Btw `Hyperlink.Address` returns a `String` so you shouldn't be attempting to use `Set` or assign it to an `Object` variable.

Comment: @BigBen That doesn't seem to work either. Thanks for the comment on the wrong variable type though, I completely looked over that.

Comment: @BigBen in this case I want to just check a test file in which I only have two sheets and 3 hyperlinks and I want to loop through these to check if I can get the right syntax to work. It just never returns anything for the hyperlink and doesn't show the msgbox.

Comment: Might be helpful to read the [`Hyperlink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink) docs. I don't know exactly your setup, but try `Set hy = sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink` and also `MsgBox hy.Address`.

Comment: Ah thanks! This is it. I had read the documentation, but I think it had something to do with mismatching variables when I tried it... So that wasn't working when I tried it. Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: There are some other problems with your code. If you want to start with a working example that you can adapt if necessary, have a look at this page on the PPT FAQ site I maintain:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm